# Is it possible to test that the correct callback function was assigned to an event handler

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function which creates a `FileReader` object and also assigns `load` and `error` handlers to it.

```
handleFileSelect(files:ArrayLike<File>):FileReader|null{
    console.log("got file upload event: ");
    console.log(" image attachment count: ",this.currentImageAttachmentCount);
    if(this.currentImageAttachmentCount >= this.maxImageAttachmentCount)
    {
      console.log("reached max attachment size");

      this.showDialog("You can't attach more files",new DialogContext("",""));
      return null;
    }
    console.log("files selected:",files);
    console.log("total selected: ",files.length);
    for(let i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
      console.log("files name:",files[i].name);
      console.log("files object:",files[i])
    }

    //working with only 1 file at the moment
    let file = files[0];
    console.log("file at index 0 ",file);
    if (files && file) {
      console.log("reading file");
      let reader:FileReader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = this.handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
      reader.onerror = this.handleFileLoadError.bind(this);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      this.currentImageAttachmentCount++;
      return reader;
    } else{
      return null;
    }

  }
```

I want to test that `handleFileSelect` has assigned the correct handlers. The test case I have written is

```
fit('should call assign correct error handler', () => {
    let newComponent = component;
    console.log("component is ",newComponent);

    let file1 = new File(["dd"], "file1",{type:'image/png'});

    let reader = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);

    expect(reader).toBeTruthy();
    console.log("reader's onerror ",reader.onerror.name);
    console.log("component's onerror ",newComponent.handleFileLoadError.name);
    expect(reader.onerror.name).toEqual(newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileLoadError.name);

  });
```

I notice that the prints in the browser console don't have function names. I expected to see `handleFileLoadError`.

`reading file`
`reader's onerror`

Why am I not seeing `handleFileLoadError`? How can I test that correct error handlers are assigned?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log()` the name property directly after its assignment?

Comment: it is empty!!! I wonder how can I check that the correct callback is assigned? or in other words, how do I check that the object assigned to `reader`'s `onerror` method is same as the `handleFileLoadError` function object?

Comment: I tried `expect(reader.onerror).toEqual(newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileLoadError)` but the test failed `Expected Function to equal Function.`

Comment: Your code should work. The name property should be available. Especially when: `reader.onerror = this.handleFileLoadError; console.log(reader.onerror.name);` Can't explain that.